# (404 Errors) Why are hackers looking for directories named "/najwutoanfga/" and other 10-12 char strings of random letters?

Tags: nginx, web-server, hacking

I was looking through the 404 errors of my nginx logs today to see what the hackers are trying to do on my website.

I usued this command:

```
cat access.log | grep '404'
```

I saw the usual requests for directories like "/admin.", "/backup/", or "/private/" but I also see a few requests like these:

```
"GET /yatjgmatiak/ HTTP/1.1"

"GET /gkjasdhytkaf/ HTTP/1.1"

"GET /ukaewlinfsda/ HTTP/1.1"

"GET /vankhasgeskl/ HTTP/1.1"
```

There aren't that many of them (only about 50 total requests) so if it were a brute force attempt at trying to find an admin panel, it would be a poor one.

What do you think these hackers are looking for or trying to do?

Comment: Possibly searching for directories infected by their (or others) malware. So they would already have a php and/or other script/executable planted on the system and they would then control that system after they get a hit. 

Or they could just be trying to scan for temporary files left by certain types of software.

Comment: Oh that makes sense. Maybe they tried an exploit that creates a file or directory and they are checking to see if that file exists? If that file exists, it must mean their exploit worked?